# FitBit Flex Active Minutes

Tags: workout

I don't understand why my FitBit will record "Active Minutes" when I workout and then when I log my "exercise" to get the calories closer, it subtracts out the time from "Active Minutes."  It's very strange to have 3 hours of being active with a sport ( like curling where I'm moving back and forth up and down the ice and sweeping a lot) and my total active minutes will read 12 minutes. Why is this? Please explain.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Fitbit product support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about product support.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your FitBit model, you may have to be moderately to extremely active for at least ten consecutive minutes to get credit for active minutes.  Otherwise you get nada.